# How to optimize WPF app launch on Windows startup

Tags: wpf, windows, startup

I implemented a WPF app and had it registered to launch at windows startup. My app is a simple logon app which when the user is logged on appears in the icon tray.The problem is that it takes about 30 seconds to show itself after Windows startup. I've tried Ngen without great success. I would like to avoid implementing a splash screen. I would like my WPF app to appear "immediately" after Windows startup similar to what Windows Live Messenger does. Anything I can do so as to reduce its startup time? Do I have any other choice than to code it natively?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Does it also take 30 seconds to start when the computer is idle (i.e if you start it by double clicking when the computer is not busy loading windows)?

During windows startup, the computer is typically busy with a lot of stuff and that could cause slowness for your application. Not much you can do then.

But, some general tips for improving startup of a WPF application:

- Only instantiate the controls you actually need to show to the user initially
- Reduce the complexity of your controls/windows.
- Don't do anything time consuming in the constructors of your controls & windows

  - Even innocent stuff like reading a file from local disk can be time consuming if the disk is busy with other stuff (like it normally is during windows startup)
  - Web service calls can take extra long time if the network hasn't been fully initialized yet
  - An easy solution is to offload heavy work to a `BackgroundWorker` or use asynchronous calls to do I/O and network requests

There is also a setting you can put in `app.config` that tells the runtime to not authenticate the assemblies with the certificate (this check can take a long time, especially cold starts):

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/> 
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Some more general tips are available on the MSDN site on [Application Startup Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656914.aspx).

Comment: No problem with a cold start on double-click, it takes about 2 seconds to launch. The problem is on windows startup. I've seen apps like Windows Live Messenger which launch themselves immediately on windows startup but these are native applications. Can I come close to something similar in WPF?

Comment: Look through your startup/constructor code and look for stuff like disk I/O and network I/O and move them to background threads/async code. Perhaps your app is blocking waiting for a network which hasn't been initialized by windows yet

Comment: @IsakSavo actually simple WPF hello world applications demonstrates the same behavior

Comment: Hmm, ok. Try with the generatePublisherEvidence setting also. I will reduce the startup time a bit, and maybe this could be extra slow during windows startup. (Although I've never seen it take 30 seconds, but who knows...)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this site](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial44.html) will be helpful to you. It lists some of the options you have for starting an application before (if it's a service) or after Windows login. They involve some registry hacking which you'll need to undo during uninstall.

Comment: I was running app that works in systray of windows and adding it to auto start on userinit registry key in link made it start immediately!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I like the [Performance Tips of the wpftutorial.net](http://www.wpftutorial.net/10PerformanceTips.html) much.

Answer (score 0):

Using regedit, Create a *DWORD* in the registry at

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Serialize

called **StartupDelayInMSec**.

Default value should be set to 0, but double check.

This cut about 10 seconds off for my application launch time after startup.

note: The Serialize Key may not exist.
You can create it by right-clicking on *Explorer* and selecting *New -> Key*